# Disk write does not work with malloc in C

Tags: c, io, disk

I did write to disk using C code.

First I tried with malloc and found that write did not work (write returned -1):

```
fd = open('/dev/sdb', O_DIRECT | O_SYNC | O_RDWR);
void *buff = malloc(512);
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
write(fd, buff, 512);
```

Then I changed the second line with this and it worked:

```
void *buff;
posix_memalign(&buff,512,512);
```

However, when I changed the lseek offset to 1: `lseek(fd, 1, SEEK_SET);`, write did not work again.

First, why didn't malloc work?

Then, I know that in my case, posix_memalign guarantees that start address of memory alignment must be multiple of 512. But, should not memory alignment and write be a separate process? So why I could not write to any offset that I want?

Comment: Did you check return of `malloc` , `write`  ??

Comment: When I say `write` did not work, it means that the retval = -1. And I have checked that malloc did not return null. @ameyCU

Comment: names starting with `/dev` in linux are special block devices. What happens if you specify an actual file instead?

Comment: @Vincentius: then you should check `errno`.

Comment: Is this a complete example? Because a newly `malloc()`ed buffer has uninitialized bytes and if you attempt to read from it without having written to it previously, the behavior is undefined. So, in particular, anything or nothing could be written to the file. Maybe you want to use `calloc` instead to get a buffer full of zero bytes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Linux man page for open(2):

> The O_DIRECT flag may impose alignment restrictions on the  length 
>   and address  of  user-space  buffers and the file offset of I/Os.

And:

> Under  Linux  2.4, transfer sizes, and the alignment of the user
>   buffer and the file offset must all be multiples of the logical block
>   size  of the filesystem.  Under Linux 2.6, alignment to 512-byte
>   boundaries suffices.

The meaning of O_DIRECT is to "try  to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this file", and if I understand it correctly it means that the kernel should copy directly from the user-space buffer, thus perhaps requiring stricter alignment of the data.

Comment: Ah great, it answers most of the problem. Btw, what I am still not clear is, why `posix_memalign` works instead of `malloc`?

Comment: Uhh because it gives you this aligned memory? :o

Comment: `posix_memalign` is like `malloc`, except that the memory it allocates is aligned. That is, it starts at a memory address which is a multiple of the second argument.

Comment: okay, just like what is stated in the second quotation in this answer, then malloc does not work because its allocation can be exist not in the "multiples of the logical block size - offset" while posix_memalign will guarantee this condition. right?

Comment: @Vincentius: Yes, that is correct. malloc is only guaranteed to align memory in a way that lets you store and access any data type, which on different processor architectures might mean a multiple of 4 or 8, or even none.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the documentation doesn't say, but it's quite possible that write and reads to/from a block device is required to be aligned and for entire blocks to succeed (this would explain why you get failure in your first and last cases but not in the second). If you use linux the documentation of open(2) basically says this:

> The O_DIRECT flag may impose alignment restrictions on the length and
>   address of user-space buffers and the file offset of I/Os.  In Linux
>   alignment restrictions vary by file system and kernel version and
>   might be absent entirely.   However  there  is  cur‐
>          rently no file system-independent interface for an application to discover these restrictions for a given file or file system.  Some
>   file systems provide their own interfaces for doing so, for example
>   the XFS_IOC_DIOINFO operation in xfsctl(3).

Your code shows lack of error handling. Every line in the code contains functions that may fail and `open`, `lseek` and `write` also reports the cause of error in `errno`. So with some kind of error handling it would be:

```
fd = open('/dev/sdb', O_DIRECT | O_SYNC | O_RDWR);

if( fd == -1 ) {
    perror("open failed");
    return;
}

void *buff = malloc(512);

if( !buff ) {
    printf("malloc failed");
    return;
}

if( lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET) == (off_t)-1 ) {
    perror("lseek failed");
    free(buff);
    return;
}

if( write(fd, buff, 512) == -1 ) {
    perror("write failed");
    free(buff);
    return;
}
```

in that case you would at least get a more detailed explaination on what goes wrong. In this case I suspect that you get EIO (Input/output error) from the `write` call.

Note that the above maybe isn't complete errorhandling as `perror` and `printf` themselves can fail (and you might want to do something about that possibility).

Comment: Thanks for your thought. Actually I do have similar error handling inside the code, I just showed the pith to show the important part and avoid long post.

Comment: @Vincentius If you have such error handling, it probably tells you more about what happened. What does `perror()` tell you?